# Instantiating a class based on a property set value

Tags: c#

When presenting the user with a `ComboBox` with `ObservableCollection<Type>` as its `ItemsSource`, how can I instantiate a class in the property that `SelectedItem` is bound to?

The elements in the `ElementList` list in `parentItem` is either of a generic class type `Element`, or is of a type inheriting from `Element` (e.g. `DigitalOutputButton` or `TrendGraph`).

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Element Type:" />
    <ComboBox Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element.ElementTypeList}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Element.SelectedElementType}" />
</StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Type> _elementTypeList 
    = new ObservableCollection<Type> { typeof(Element), typeof(DigitalOutputButton), typeof(TrendGraph) };
public static ObservableCollection<Type> ElementTypeList { get { return _elementTypeList; } }

public Type SelectedElementType {
    get { return GetType(); }
    set {
        if (value != GetType()) {
            var parentItem = Controller.ConfigurationHandler.FindParentItem(this);
            var currentItemIndex = parentItem.ElementList.IndexOf(this);
            parentItem.ElementList[currentItemIndex] = new typeof(value)();
        }
    }
}
```

The above `set` code will not build.  But is it possible to achieve this behavior in another way?

**EDIT:** Ok, this way works:

```
public Type SelectedElementType {
    get { return GetType(); }
    set {
        if (value != GetType()) {
            var parentItem = Controller.ConfigurationHandler.FindParentItem(this);
            var currentItemIndex = parentItem.ElementList.IndexOf(this);
            if (value == typeof(Element)) {
                parentItem.ElementList[currentItemIndex] = new Element();
            }
            else if (value == typeof(DigitalOutputButton)) {
                parentItem.ElementList[currentItemIndex] = new DigitalOutputButton();
            }
            else if (value == typeof(TrendGraph)) {
                parentItem.ElementList[currentItemIndex] = new TrendGraph();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be great it there was a way to do this that were a little more "maintenance free" (no need to edit when adding a new element type).

Comment: You can set initial value `SelectedElementType 
 = ElementTypeList.FirstOrDefault()` or any other item *from* that collection. The rest will be done by the binding.

Comment: @Sinatr Not sure how your solution will help me...

Comment: Why do you use `GetType()` in getter/setter of property bound to `ComboBox.SelectedItem`? You don't have to (and my first comment apply) or I don't understand something. It seems you are not planning to change `SelectedElementType` from code-behind, then just let the view (binding) to handle it.

Comment: @Sinatr Exactly.  The `SelectedItem` value of the `ComboBox` in the XAML is bound to the `SelectedElementType` property, and is a two-way binding.  When the user selects a type other than the one that the selected element currently is, the selected element is to be replaced with a new instance of the newly selected type.  The `GetType()` is just for initally setting the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` to the selected element's current type.

Comment: Does `Activator.CreateInstance(value)` work for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity This turned out to be the right direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(value, Controller, ParentElementGroup, ItemLabel);
parentItem.ElementList[currentItemIndex] = (TYPE)instance;
```

The only missing link is the type of your collection so it can be cast. But that should be compile time knowledge.

Comment: Excellent, this was exactly what I needed.  It's "ParentElementGroup" rather than "parentItem".  But other than that, casting the instance to the generic class "Element" that all the specific element classes inherits from worked like a charm.